# Django rest create new user when creating object from post

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I want the walking customer of my app to be able to ask for a rendez-vous i wish 
 to create automatically a new user anytime a new username is sent by post with the rendez-vous data and a default password

here is my view.py

```
class rvList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
queryset = Rendezvous.objects.all() 
serializer_class = RvSerializer


def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Here is my serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

class RvSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Rendezvous
        fields = ('id','daterv', 'heurerv', 'lieurv','owner')
```

Please can you help me solve that problem i want to insert some data from post to User model and the rest to RendezVous model

i am getting this

```
   {
    "id": 11,
    "daterv": "2013-02-01",
    "heurerv": "10:30",
    "lieurv": "Thies",
    "owner": {
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": ""
    }
},
{
    "id": 12,
    "daterv": "2013-02-01",
    "heurerv": "08:30",
    "lieurv": "Dakar",
    "owner": null
},
```

Only logged user is set with the related rv not the new user i have sent with my form.
 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that your are not filling the serialier with post data.

In this part:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

self.request.user is authenticated user (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#user) which is actualy null by default when user is not logged in.

If you want to create user from data sent by post method, you should be able to access them in self.request.data (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data)

Comment: Tkx you made my day !!!!  just for other who will face this problem dont forget to specify the nested field i did this to get the data from Post with @Matus help                                                                                                                     username=self.request.data.get('owner',dict()).get('username')                                       and    serializer.save(owner=user)